# Adding labels to nodes in Flowing Data Interactive Network Demo

Tags: d3.js, coffeescript

I tried adding permanent labels (names of nodes) to the Interactive Network Demo shared by Jim. (https://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/)

Being a novice in D3 and Coffee, I couldn't achieve the goal despite spending good amount of time trying to understand D3 and Coffee scripting.

Following is the coffee script  i tried to add:

```
node.enter().append("text")
.attr("cx", (d) -> d.x)
.attr("cy", (d) -> d.y)
.text("text", (d) -> d.name)
```

Some help in achieving the same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That example uses D3 v3.x. Unfortunately, there is a "magic" in v 3.x that will prevent you to achieve what you want (not to mention that `text` doesn't have `cx` or `cy`):

This is the `node` selection, which is the data binding selection:

```
node = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node")
.data(curNodesData, (d) -> d.id)
```

However, the next line is:

```
node.enter().append("circle")
```

And here comes the problematic magic:

The `enter` and `append` modify the data binding selection. So, when after that you try to append a text to `node`, you're actually appending a `text` element to a `circle` element, and that will not work!

Solution: create SVG groups, where you can append both circles and texts.

Comment: PS: that "magic" was removed in d3 v4.x. Another Post Scriptum: I can't inspect the source because I'm on my mobile, but I bet that the code you linked *already* have groups.